# Last Matrix operation ignored?

Tags: java, android, matrix, transformation, scale

I have 2 methods, one to rotate my Quad and one to flip it (using scaleM), they are as follows: (Note, all values in these methods have been properly defined).

If I call just one, they work as expected, but if I call both, then only the one that is called last if applied - why is this?  If I combine them into on 'flip and rotate method' - then my quad is both flipped and rotated. (See third code snippet)

Why is this?

**Method to rotate**

```
    public void rotate(float x, float y, int angle){

    //Rotate the quad

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, centreX, centreY, 0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -angle, 0, 0, 0.1f);
    Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -centreX, -centreY, 0f);

}
```

**Method to 'flip' (horizontally)**

```
    public void flipHorizontal(float x, float y){

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, centreX, centreY, 0f);
    Matrix.scaleM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -1, 1, 0f);
    Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -centreX, -centreY, 0f);
}
```

**Combined method**

```
    public void flipHorizontal(float x, float y, int angle){

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, centreX, centreY, 0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 0.1f);
    Matrix.scaleM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -1, 1, 0f);
    Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -centreX, -centreY, 0f);


}
```

Comment: A downvote with no explanation.  This helps nobody.  What's the point of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s because you set "mRotationMatrix" to Identity in the beginning of each method, which basically resets every previous operation. Try to call "Matrix.setIdentityM" only once outside of these functions.